# CoGAPS installation

Tags: r

I've successfully installed all required software to run CoGAPS.  I am now following the manual, where I am in the R console (I am using a MAC btw).  When I follow the steps (even the alternatives provided), I get the following:

```
>source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
Bioconductor version 2.12 (BiocInstaller 1.10.4), ?biocLite for help
A newer version of Bioconductor is available for this version of R, ?BiocUpgrade for help
> biocLite("CoGAPS")
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 2.12 (BiocInstaller 1.10.4), R version 3.0.1.
Installing package(s) 'CoGAPS'

package ‘CoGAPS’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning message:
package ‘CoGAPS’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

Any R programmers who may have experienced this issue with another package?  Is it because CoGAPS may not be compatible for R 3.0.1?  Or maybe it is the location of the folder?  I have both the unzipped and zipped files from the primary source website, so the binary should be included?

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: have you tried installing from source? e.g. `biocLite("CoGAPS", type="source")`

Comment: no. I had tried something similar, but I tried as you said, Stephen, and I get the following error:
llvm-g++-4.2 -arch x86_64-I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include - DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include/GAPS-JAGS -I/usr/local/include -fPIC -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c jags.cc -o jags.o
make: llvm-g++-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [jags.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘CoGAPS’
I checked the location of 'jags.o' and didn't find one.  I did find the directory JAGS under /usr/local/include which doesn't contain 'jag.o'.  In fact, I've been unable to locate the file.

Comment: okay.  So to fix this llvm-g++-4.2 error, I've changed set CC = clang and CCX = clang++ (they were previously set to llvm-g++-4.2, which I do not have).  I did this inside /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc.  Then I redo the biocLite command and get the following error: "** libs
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf:25: *** missing separator.  Stop."  I'm not sure how to handle this.   Thanks!